# Constructor initializer list and static member (private vs protected)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, initializer-list

It is clear that a data member of a class declared as `static` is incorrect to be initialized in ctor initializer list (because it "is not a member" of an object). But it works fine if it is a `protected` member. Why?

```
// foo.h
class Foo {
public:
  explicit Foo();
  ~Foo() = default;
protected:
  static int kProtected;
private:
  static int kPrivate;
}
```

```
// foo.cpp
Foo::Foo() 
    : kProtected(1), // OK (?!)
      kPrivate(1) {} // error C2438: 'kPrivate': cannot initialize static class data via constructor
```

Comment: I got 2 errors as expected on MSVC v19: https://godbolt.org/z/AXorG-

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using?

Answer (score 1):

From §10.3.8.2 Classes/Static members/Static data members of the draft C++20 standard:

> Static data members are initialized and destroyed exactly like non-local variables.

so your compiler is incorrect.

Comment: "Your compiler is incorrect" against a draft version of a standard? That's a bit far-fetched statement. Especially when question has `c++11` tag.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen It's not "a bit far-fetched" at all. That's just the latest spec - they all say it. C++17 standard §12.2.3.2: "Static data members are initialized and destroyed exactly like non-local variables". C++14 standard §9.4.2: "Static data members are initialized and destroyed exactly like non-local variables". The C++11 standard has it in the exact same place as the C++14 standard: §9.4.2: "Static data members are initialized and destroyed exactly like non-local variables".

Answer (score 0):

Which version of visual studio are you using? Older visual studios were notorious for treating standard more as a guide. On clang your code gets:

```
<source>:12:7: error: member initializer 'kProtected' does not name a non-static data member or base class

    : kProtected(1), // OK (?!)

      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~

<source>:13:7: error: member initializer 'kPrivate' does not name a non-static data member or base class

      kPrivate(1) {} // error

      ^~~~~~~~~~~

2 errors generated.
```

Comment: This is not really an answer but a comment.  Please don't abuse the answer box